# VB.NET Expected type int32

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am using the following code to import data from a CSV file to a datatable :
When I run my application I get the following error : Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in PLANTJAAR Column.  Expected type is Int32.
This happens at the second last line : datatabel.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())

```
 Dim datatabel As New DataTable()

   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("LIDNOMMER", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("LIDNAAM", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PLAASNOMMER", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PLAASNAAM", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("BLOKNO", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("AREA", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("KLAS", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("GROND", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("BESPROEI", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PLANTJAAR", GetType(Int32)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("STADIUM", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ONDERSTOK", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("KULTIVAR", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("OPP", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ALIAS", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ALIASNAAM", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("KONTAK1", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("KONTAK2", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("KLAAR_EZY", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MASJIEN", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PROD_GROEP", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("E_POS_DOC", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("E_POS_HAR", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("E_POS_REM", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("DOELWIT", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("OESMETODE", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SNOEIMETODE", GetType(String)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_MIN5", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_MIN4", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_MIN3", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_MIN2", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_MIN1", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_HUIDIG", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TONHA_MIN5", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TONHA_MIN4", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TONHA_MIN3", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TONHA_MIN2", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TONHA_MIN1", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TONHA_HUIDIG", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_SKAT_HAND", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_SKAT_MASJIEN", GetType(Decimal)))
   datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TON_SKAT_TOTAAL", GetType(Decimal)))

   Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\EZY    Wine Data\skedp_01.csv")
   parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
   parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

   parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

   parser.ReadLine()

   Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
       datatabel.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())

   Loop
```

I have no empty rows in the column plantjaar in the CSV file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT : My CSV file :

Comment: Show us the content of a CSV file that creates this error. I guess it does have an empty string for that column in a row.

Comment: look for this <> as it is not an integer

Answer (score 0):

you define your PLANTJAAR column like the following

```
datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PLANTJAAR", GetType(Int32)))
```

Int32 means that numbers with no decimal digits can be stored in that column.

My guess is that you have either some form of string or numbers with decimal digits in your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to check the field you need.

In this case, if it's not an int32, you'll set it to 0.  Ideally, you should check ALL your fields.

```
Do Until parser.EndOfData = True

   Dim fields() as String = parser.ReadFields()
   Dim checkIndex as Integer = 9 ' Index of PLANTJAAR Field
   Dim checkNum as Integer = 0

   If Not Int32.TryParse(fields(checkIndex), checkNum) Then
       fields(9) = "0"
   End If

   datatabel.Rows.Add(fields)

Loop
```